# php- How to compare two times?

Tags: php

I am making a missed call phone verification system in which a user has to do a missed from his phone within 2 minutes of registration to verify his registration. Upon successful registration, the registration time is saved in database in format like 07:55:43 (hr:min:sec).

What I want to do is that user has to do missed call within 2 minutes of registration only (I can also get the time of when he called in hr:min:sec format) & if he doesn't  do call in 2 minutes then die() should execute..

How can I do that?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803856/php-comparing-time

Answer (score 0):

Add the start of the 2 minute time out to the form in a hidden field.  You may have to mix it up so it cannot be altered.

How do you do a missed call?

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

echo "<input type="hidden" name="time" value="$time">
```